# How do I store and access a value on an iFrame's parent using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, iframe, parent, store

I have a website that consists of one parent page. Using the lightbox-style jQuery plugin colorbox I open other pages in iFrames that float on top of the parent page, overlay style.

In the javascript code on the iFrame pages I load JSON data from Facebook. Since the data loading from facebook takes time I want to store the data I've loaded in a variable that lives on the parent page.

Then each time I open a new iFrame in an overlay, I want to be able to check if the parent page variable is empty or not. If it's empty, I load the data from Facebook. If it's not empty, I get the data from the variable on the parent page.

The only reason I want to do this is increasing performance and avoiding unnecessary calls to the Facebook API.

**How do I create a solution where a javascript in an iFrame can store and access data from a variable that lives on its parent page?**

I don't have real code, but in pseudo code I'd like something like this:

```
function loadFacebookFriends() {
   if(parentFriendsVariable is empty) {
      Load friends from Facebook
   }
   else {
      localFriendsVariable = parentFriendsVariable
   }
}
```

The call to the Facebook API looks like this:

```
FB.api("/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,picture", function(friendsData) {
    // When this callback is executed, the data I want is
    // now in the object:
    friendsData.data
});
```

On the parent page my javascript code is in a jQuery document ready tag.

Thanks in advance!

/Thomas Kahn

Comment: Is the parent and the child "IFrames" live in the same domain?

Comment: can't you use wondow.parent.<variable>?

Comment: Yes, both the parent and the Iframes are loaded from the same web server on the same domain. I have done experiments using window.parent.variable, but it doesn't work like I expect it. Could the fact that my code is wrapped in jQuery be the cause?

Comment: It sounds to me like the variable you want to access in the parent frame is not exposed in global scope. As msuhash said, if the frames are in the same domain you can access a parent global variable called foo with 'parent.foo'.  If however your variable is defined within your jQuery doc ready event (e.g. $("document").ready( function() { var foo = 23; } ); then the variable is only accessible inside that function.

Comment: I tried declaring the variable outside the jQuery scope, but that didn't work either. Perhaps it's because I'm trying to access it while I'm inside the jQuery scope on the IFrame page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The real source of it was not accessing the variable, but an error in how and when I accessed the variables in my javascript. When I declared the variables outside of jQuery in the parent page, like this:

```
   var friendsCache = new Object;
```

...it worked! In my IFrame page I can access the value like this:

```
   var friends = window.parent.friendsCache;
```

So now I have a solution that looks something like this. When the user has logged in successfully with Facebook Connect, I call the function loadFriends:

```
function loadFriends() {
   if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(friends)) {
      FB.api("/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,picture", renderFriends);
   }
   else {
      renderFriends();
   }
}

function renderFriends(friendsData) {
   if (friendsData != undefined) {
      if (!(jQuery.isEmptyObject(friendsData))) {
         friends = friendsData.data;
         window.parent.friendsCache = friends;
      }
   }
   // Do the stuff you want to do when the friends are loaded
}
```

As long as the parent page isn't reloaded, I don't need to load the list of Facebook friends from the Graph API. Instead I load them from my cache variable, which gives me a highly noticeable increase in performance.

Eventhough this description was a little broader in scope than my original question, I hope someone will find it useful.

/Thomas Kahn